# How to read x-y values from one file and data from another in d3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a .csv file with a large number of values which will act as the x & y axis.
a,b
1,2
3,4
5,6 etc

Now i have a another .csv file which has some "data" values for corresponding a & b. I would like to create a scatter plot with different colors depending upon the range in which "data" values fall. Since a & b are fixed and "data" could change I would like to have separate files for both.

I tried something like this:

```
var mycolor=["#00008F","#00009F","#0000AF","#0000BF","#0000CF",
                        "#0000DF","#0000EF","#0000FF","#000FFF","#001FFF",
                        "#002FFF","#003FFF","#004FFF","#005FFF","#006FFF",];           
d3.csv("file1.csv",function(d1)
            {
                var i;
                var mydata1=d1;

svg.selectAll(".circle").attr("class", "bubble").data(mydata1).enter().append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d){ return scaleX(d.a);})
                .attr("cy", function(d){return scaleY(d.b);})
                .attr({
                        "r": 3,
                        "fill-opacity": 0.1,
                        })
                .style("fill", function(d)
                        {    d3.csv("file2.csv",function(d2){
                                var mydata2=d2;
                            for(i=0;i<15;i++)
                            {
                                if (mydata2.data>=0 && mydata2.data<=1)
                                    return mycolor[0];
                                else if (mydata2.data>i && mydata2.data<=(i+1)) 
                                    return mycolor[i];
                            }
                        });
                });
            });
```

This is working, but it doesnt show the color according to my condition. Could somebody point out whats wrong with the code?

EDIT:With recommendations from @UberKaeL, my new code is this:

```
queue().defer(d3.csv, "file1.csv").defer(d3.csv, "file2.csv").await(mapping);

function mapping(error,mydata1,mydata2){
var mycolor=["#00008F","#00009F","#0000AF","#0000BF","#0000CF",
                        "#0000DF","#0000EF","#0000FF","#000FFF","#001FFF",
                        "#002FFF","#003FFF","#004FFF","#005FFF","#006FFF",];
            var i;
            svg.selectAll(".circle").attr("class", "bubble").data(mydata1).enter().append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d){ return scaleX(d.a);})
                .attr("cy", function(d){return scaleY(d.b);})
                .attr({
                        "r": 3,
                        "fill-opacity": 0.1,
                        })
                .style("fill", function(d)
                        {  console.log("updated");
                           for(i=0;i<64;i++)
                           {
                                if (mydata2.data>=0 && mydata2.data<=1)
                                    return mycolor[0];
                                else if (mydata2.data>i && mydata2.data<=(i+1)) 
                                    return mycolor[i];
                            }
                        });
}
```

But still the issue of color exists.

Comment: There is not `for` loop so the style function does nothing. If you are using two datasets the canonical d3 style is to use two _select-data(mydata2)-enter_ and only update elements in the second one.

Comment: remove .style part and do a new select with new data. `svg.selectAll(".circle").data(mydata2).enter().style("fill", function(d) {return mycolor[whatever math with d]})`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [D3 queue library](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) (from d3 author) to charge the data.
as example:

```
queue()
.defer(d3.json, "file.json")
.defer(d3.tsv, "names.tsv")
.defer(d3.csv, "file2.csv")
.await(ready);
```

and then

```
function ready(error, data1, data2, data3) { yourcode }
```

it will wait until all read functions will finish.

Edit: in your program will like that

```
queue()
.defer(d3.csv, "file1.csv")
.defer(d3.csv, "file2.csv")
.await(ready);

function ready(error, dataXY, datafile2) { yourcode }
```

Now you can use dataXY and datafile2 with `.data()`

Comment: okay i understood the use of queue... But can you please elaborate how data1, data2 etc were created? like do I have to write seperate d3.csv(file,function(d){data1=d;}) code for each file?

Comment: No, ready function will take data1 from "file.json", data2 from "names.tsv" and data3 from "file2.csv" using d3 read functions (first argument). Then you can work inside ready() as you was doing, using data1 for x y values and data2 for you data.

Comment: Ok, understood. But still it didnt solve my color issue. The points are all black :(

Comment: a tip, use a color scale `var escala=d3.scale.linear().domain([0, mydata2.data]).range(mycolor)` and `.style("fill", function(d) { return escala(mydata2.data); })`  **(BTW fill is style, not attr, at least not in all browsers)**

Comment: okay, so changed d "attr" to "style". It was working fine with other plotting, so didnt realize.  Also added color scale, and respective changes to "style" but no effect

Comment: @Sush After declaring `var i` it never gets updated and will therefore be `undefined` throughout your code which consequently won't allow accessing array `mycolor`.

Comment: @Sush Did you notice that your `svg.selectAll(".circle").attr("class", "bubble")` will assign class `bubble` only to those circles already present in the svg, i.e. those which are in D3's update selection. You are binding data afterwards but in the enter selection this class is never assigned which might not be what you are after.

Comment: @altocumulus it is there in my code but while copying & editing here somehow it got deleted. So I have added it here again. And about the "class bubble", I couldn't understand what you are trying to imply.